# json_encode of mysqli query strange array result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I want to get the result of a sql query to javascript. Therefore I found many solutions which suggest to use the json_encode method. I wrote this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT idDozent FROM Dozent;";
    $rows = array();
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
```

Now in my javascript code I wrote:

```
var jsonarray = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
```

My table looks like this:

```
idDozent | Name
7        | ...
8        | ...
```

But the array contains:

```
[{"0":"7","idDozent":"7"},{"0":"8","idDozent":"8"}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

And how can I access one record of the array?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is exactly the expected result, you can access it in JS via `jsonarray[0].idDozent` ie

Comment: That array is fine: `alert(jsonarray[0].idDozent);`

Comment: Ah okay, so I haven't done something wrong, just didnt know how to access it. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for a `while` loop since you're just recreating the same array to be encoded. Just need to use [fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead. `$rows = $result->fetch_all();`

Comment: "SELECT * FROM Dozent;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That javascript array is fine, however if you dont want the duplication in the array (numerical and string property names), then alter your mysql query to return associative array:

```
//while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
...

var jsonarray = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
console.log(jsonarray[0].idDozent);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$rows[$row['idDozent']] = $row['Name'];
```

when you use `$rows[] = ...` as in your code php automatically add the key to your array. Instead of this, you can specify your own keys! But aware to use duplicated keys.